# Drupal6 - Develop mobile site

Tags: drupal-6

Hi
I am going to develop a Drupal site for mobile, suppose I will coding with the template file, anyone can suggest some reference/tools for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use http://drupal.org/project/mobile_theme module.